# pandas.isin() function returns True for cells that have the value 'None' Python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sample Data 1:

```
Country  Year
   A     2000
   A     2000
  None   2000
```

Sample Data 2:

```
Country  Year
   A     2001
   B     2001
  None   2001
```

Output:

```
Country  
  True     
  False   
  True
```

Function(Gives None for empty Values)

```
df = df.loc[df['Country'].isin(list)]
```

No matter what I tried, isin keeps giving None for the emptyl cells values. Later I apply another isin to check if a column is in another column, however, that also counts "None" as True. Any help is much appreciated.

The second function I use is(This is the one that gives True for Nulls):

```
df['2000'].isin(df['2001'])* 1
```

I tried all the following and they didn't work.

```
df['name'].isnull()
df.fillna('')
```

Comment: try filtering the null values out first `df = df.loc[(df['Country'].notnull()) & (df['Country'].isin(list))]`

Comment: Didn't work. I just updated the question by including my second function. The second one gives True for None values. @EdChum

Comment: Please post raw data, code to create your df and your attempts with associated errors that reproduces these errors to avoid ambiguity, debugging by explaining the symptoms using text is error-prone

Comment: Just updated. @EdChum

Comment: Sorry are these string 'None', object `None` or `NaN`? I asked for raw data, not a text representation of your data, for instance I don't know what `None` here means

Comment: Note that `fillna` does not fill in place, it *returns* a new dataframe with the NaNs filled. You want `df = df.fillna('')`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `None` to `NaN` before and then check by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) by condition with functions [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: None}, 
                    'Year': {0: 2001, 1: 2001, 2: 2001}})
print (df2)
  Country  Year
0       A  2000
1       A  2000
2    None  2000

df2['Country'] = df2['Country'].replace({None: np.nan})
print (df2)
  Country  Year
0       A  2001
1       B  2001
2     NaN  2001

L = ['A','C']
df = df2[(df2['Country'].notnull()) & (df2['Country'].isin(L))]
print (df)
  Country  Year
0       A  2001
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: None}, 
                    'Year': {0: 2000, 1: 2000, 2: 2000}})
print (df1)
  Country  Year
0       A  2000
1       A  2000
2    None  2000

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: None}, 
                    'Year': {0: 2001, 1: 2001, 2: 2001}})
print (df2)
  Country  Year
0       A  2001
1       B  2001
2    None  2001

mask = df2['Country'].isin(df1['Country']) & 
      (df1['Country'].notnull()) &
      (df2['Country'].notnull())
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Country, dtype: bool

print (mask.astype(int))
0    1
1    0
2    0
Name: Country, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to change the None values to NaN. However, `df['2000'].isin(df['2001'])* 1` still gives True for NaNs

Comment: I dont understand `df['2000']` - `2000` is column what is not in sample?

Comment: And when using 'df['2000'].isin(df['2001'].notnull())* 1' Turns the entire column to False. @jezrael